# Unable to load animation.json file to my flutter project

Tags: json, flutter, android-animation, lottie, bodymovin

I exported animation.json file from Aftereffect using bodymovin and I can't load it to my flutter project.

I followed this medium [article](https://medium.com/@klickworld.chinedu/flutter-animations-adobe-after-effect-3d1b5732c240) and I was unable to render the animation, also after putting the file path in assets at the pubspec.yaml file.

I tried to simplify my code to this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            // Load a Lottie file from your assets
            Lottie.asset('assets/optimal.json'),

            // Load a Lottie file from a remote url
            Lottie.network(
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xvrh/lottie-flutter/master/example/assets/Mobilo/A.json'),

            // Load an animation and its images from a zip file
            // Lottie.asset('assets/lottiefiles/angel.zip'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the error message:

```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * Where: Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line:
> 904
> 
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> > Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> 
> * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> 
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> 
> BUILD FAILED in 44s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you added lottie folder or file to your pubdpec.yaml file of project like this

```
flutter:
assets:
- assets/images/
- assets/lottieFiles/   //this is an example of lottie file on your assets
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to delete `pubspec.lock` and install packages with `flutter pub get`.